# Differential equation with ellipsoidal symmetry

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetry

I wish to solve a given PDE with ellipsoidal symmetry (I'm not sure the wording is correct). For example it could be a PDE describing the temperature field in a bottle. I am thinking of using the symmetry to solve my problem: I should be able to define a mapping from the ellipse to a sphere and obtain a new PDE that has spherical symmetry and is easily solvable. It seems reasonable to me although I can't proof it will give me the correct solution. The idea is very simple but I can't find any papers discussing "solving PDE with ellipsoidal symmetry."

Can it work? Any references discussing this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, speaking of differential equations, you should distinguish the following notions:

1. The type of PDE. The second-order differential equations can be either elliptic, hyperbolic, or parabolic. Begin [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order).
2. The symmetry group of the differential equation. These are the transformations which typically a) leave the differential equation unchanged b) transform one of its solutions into another. The knowledge of these symmetries can be helpful for solving the equation. Begin with the classic [Olver's treatise](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=999573334134098764580B820B6DE0F7). Or with a [good book by Cantwell](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CA73E7970787EE4C6C24F44F75515DBC). (the latter also includes very cool [software](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=BBA9BA2C370ACE30CA0908822257F363))
3. Finally, given a concrete equation, it's solution may be rather simple if you are supposed to solve it with some nice boundary/initial solutions. In this case you should use the coordinate symmetries of your space (which is probably your case).

As far as I know, the items 2 and 3 are not related to each other.

Said so, I guess you probably should try switching to [elliptic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system).